# How do I import this WSDL?

Tags: delphi, wsdl, delphi-2010, soap-client

I received a WSDL from a client, as part of importing a web service to interoperate with their system.  They sent two files: a WSDL and a schema.  When I run the WSDL importer, I get an output that looks like this:

```
type

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Embarcadero types; however, they could also
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:LoadData     - "http://client.com/"[Lit][]
  // !:LoadDataResponse - "http://client.com/"[Lit][]


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // Namespace : http://client.com/
  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // style     : document
  // binding   : ClientPortBinding
  // service   : ClientService
  // port      : ClientPort
  // URL       : http://localhost:8080/ClientService
  // ************************************************************************ //
  IClientLoad = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{8DC02C6F-78D3-E09A-FE43-EE5211DB188D}']

    // Cannot unwrap:
    //     - Input part does not refer to an element
    //     - Output part does not refer to an element
    function  LoadDataBatch(const parameters: LoadData): LoadDataResponse; stdcall;
  end;
```

The missing types are defined in the schema file they sent.  I tried changing the WSDL's import line to look like this, but it didn't change anything:

`<xsd:import namespace="http://client.com/" schemaLocation="file://C:/Users/mwheeler/Documents/WSDL/ClientLoadData Schema.xml"></xsd:import>`

How do I set this up properly so Delphi's WSDL import wizard will examine the schema file on my local system and read the type definitions from it?

Comment: I have not tried it but there is an option in the WSDL importer. `Process included and imported schemas`. Sounds like what you need. Default is on so you probably already have that.

Comment: We had that kind of trouble at work just using our own services and clients. It was something to do with the D2010 import refusing elements of non-standard types, not even when they were defined explicitely in the name space. I think they solved it by only using standard data types in the soap interface. If you haven't found an answer by tomorrow morning (UTC+1), I'll check with my colleagues.

Comment: @duffymo: Please read the question carefully. I didn't include the WSDL in the question, only (an anonymized version of) the output.  This is specifically a Delphi WSDL Importer question; not a WSDL/XML question.

Comment: @Mikael: That option was already checked, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: `Process included and imported` not only is it default on, apparently you can not turn it off :)  http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=81513

Comment: Hello, make sure you add the <xsd:import ...> inside the <xsd:schema ..> element. The importer will show at the top of the file any imported/includes schema(s) that it followed.

Comment: I don't believe that's documented but you can also pass a schema directly to the WSDL Importer by using the -schema option. As in:  WSDLImp -schema  filename.xsd

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be on the import side, but rather on the export side. The situation we had:

- A Delphi coded server application that also responds to SOAP webrequests.
- A .Net coded client application that uses SOAP to communicate with the Delphi server application.

The Delphi server application would not and will not export a specific (base) type in its WSDL response if that (base) type is not used in any of the exported SOAP interfaces.

Example:

```
TBaseReponseClass = class(TRemotable)
end;

TLoginResponseClass = class(TBaseReponseClass)
end;

ISOAPResponse = interface(IInvokable)
['{SomeGUID}']
  function Ping: TBaseReponseClass ; stdcall
  function Login: TLoginResponseClass ; stdcall;
end;
```

With the Ping function in the ISOAPResponse, everything functions normally.

Without the Ping function in the ISOAPResponse, the TBaseResponseClass won't be exported in the WSDL and importing the WSDL on the .Net side would throw errors about undefined elements.

I suppose you can check the WSDL you got from your client to see whether it uses any classes for which one or more of classes in the ancestor hierarchy are not included in the WSDL/Schema. If this is the case, then you might have to go back to your clients to have them amend the interfaces. Or, if you are lucky, perhaps find some options to have ancestor classes that are not directly referenced included in the WSDL/Schema. We did not investigate the latter as we have both applications under our own control and it was easier to simply add the "Ping" function.